# Office 2010 like list view items style?

Tags: c#, wpf, fluent, listviewitem, office-2010

[image: OneNote 2010 - Backstage Menu - New tab]
This is an Office 2010 list view, with their items styled... both hovered and pressed/selected.
How can I use the items style in WPF list view items?
I use the [Fluent Ribbon Control Suite](http://fluent.codeplex.com) for my UI, and there are the right colors for this.
I just don't have any clue how to apply them to `ListViewItem`s.
Please, how do I make the style?

**Edit**: I know how to style elements... It's just that I don't know how to apply this style, as it is a little more complex. For example, there are **2 borders**.
I tried putting styles in each border in the template, but I cannot find (through the individual styles) whether the item is selected.
I also tried putting `TargetName`s in the items' style, but an error said I cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I set the `Template` property in a `Setter` in the `Style`, and I tried binding to non-`ListViewItem` properties inside it, and it worked!

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Border Background="{DynamicResource TransparentBrush}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource TransparentBrush}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="border" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Border Background="{DynamicResource TransparentBrush}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource TransparentBrush}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" Height="Auto" Name="border1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FileName}" TextAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Width="Auto" />
                </Border>
            </Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonPressedOuterBorderBrush}" />
                    <Setter Property="Border.Background" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonPressedOuterBackgroundBrush}" />
                    <Setter Property="Border.Background" TargetName="border1" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonPressedInnerBackgroundBrush}" />
                    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border1" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonPressedInnerBorderBrush}" />
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                        <Condition Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border1" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonHoverInnerBorderBrush}" />
                    <Setter Property="Border.Background" TargetName="border1" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonHoverInnerBackgroundBrush}" />
                    <Setter Property="Border.Background" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonHoverOuterBackgroundBrush}" />
                    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonHoverOuterBorderBrush}" />
                </MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="UIElement.IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border1" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonHoverInnerBorderBrush}" />
                    <Setter Property="Border.Background" TargetName="border1" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonHoverInnerBackgroundBrush}" />
                    <Setter Property="Border.Background" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonHoverOuterBackgroundBrush}" />
                    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonHoverOuterBorderBrush}" />
                </MultiTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Here, the property `FileName` is (obviously) not part of ListViewItem, it's part of my class that I put into the `ListView`. It's on line 6.

For those who want the theme, it's there, in the `ControlTemplate.Triggers`!
You need [Fluent](http://fluent.codeplex.com) for the resources (brushes) I used. I took them from the style of a `Fluent.Button`.

Just replace the TextBlock with your data template and you'll be alright! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.itemcontainerstyle.aspx) to define a style for your items, to change the appearance for those states you can use [`Triggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Trigger.aspx) that trigger on [`IsSelected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.isselected.aspx) and [`IsMouseOver`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ismouseover.aspx), how you achieve this particular outcome in the end is up to you...

Comment: I forgot to specify why I need help.

Comment: @Vercas: Not quite sure i understand, if you want to apply complex changes you can change the `Template` in a setter inside the trigger. Have you tried that?

Comment: I didn't... I already have a custom template for my items, which aren't actually `ListViewItems`, they are `MyProgram.Data.Item`, which isn't even an UI component. But, I will try this. It sounds like it might just work!

Comment: That was really not maintainable... So I tried binding to non-`ListViewItem` properties in my `ControlTemplate` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do not want to re-invent the wheel?
http://www.devcomponents.com/blog/?p=581

I use those components and they are beautiful.

The real point here is, this is not a trivial task.

Check out how the real button is made: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx and you will get what I mean.

Comment: No commercial stuff. I will reinvent the wheel if others' wheel costs money. By the way, why should I see how the real button is made?

Comment: The point is around the complexity. Specifically that you will need to style more states than the three you identify. Disabled and Default for example. And there are storyboards you need, too - not just styles. So these commercial buttons are good choices because they look EXACTLY like you want. Consider your time versus the $300 - but it's up to you. Here's an idea, open the trial version in Blend and extract their styles and templates. That will get you quite far and give you something to reference that's much like what you want. Best of luck.

Comment: My mother (my only parent) makes $400 a month. Shall we (me, mom and my brother) starve for a few weeks so I can buy that?

Comment: That's why I said extract the style from the Trial.

Comment: In the end, I extracted the style from the Fluent controls.

Comment: You should post them for the next developer.